# Where can I find SerialMonitor.java in installed Arduino IDE 1.8.13?

Tags: serial, ubuntu, installation

I have found the git source for SerialMonitor (`Arduino/app/src/processing/app/*`) but unable to find it in the installed Arduino IDE. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit.

I want to make changes to it, not so much a terminal emulator but just perform simple ASCII control characters like backspace (0x08). Some advice on replacing it would be appreciated too; I guess it involves `jar` files (I am not a java developer).

I have read elsewhere about (and used) various other terminal-type programs, but of course they stop the IDE from uploading sketches. So not much good for development.

Or if anyone knows of an already-improved Serial Monitor, and how to install it for the IDE, then that could be perfect.

Comment: IDE development is not an Arduino topic. Java is compiled so you will not find the source codes in distribution. only the built-in Serial Monitor knows when the IDE uploads

Comment: @Juraj please advise where https://github.com/arduino/Arduino topic discussions take place, if not in arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/arduino.cc/forum/#!forum/developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found that [Building Arduino - Steps for First Time Setup](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Building-Arduino) was good. It was tricky to find; most searches for 'Build Arduino' assume it's a project with an Arduino, rather than the IDE.

By building this way, I could change the source, then inside the `build` folder run `ant run`. So, no need to actually know where it goes.

I had a problem with it grumbling about
`Incorrect IDE installation folder:  Your copy of the IDE is installed in a subfolder of your sketchbook. Please move the IDE to another folder.`
which would have been more useful if it had said WHAT settings needed changing.

It turns out that `preferences.txt` had a conflict with settings `sketchbook.path` and `runtime.ide.path`. I changed `sketchbook.path`. All is now good.

Comment: Ah, yes. The anonymous down-voters. Some people just don't want this knowledge shared,

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "find and replace" that file.

Java isn't distributed as source code. It's compiled "bytecode" that isn't modifiable by a human.

You would need to download *all* the source code, make your changes to it, and then recompile it.

Or, simpler: just use a more capable serial terminal program, such as "Putty" or "TeraTerm" in Windows, or "Minicom" or "Screen" on Linux. I have no idea what is available for OS X.

Comment: Screen works out of box in OS X too.

Comment: A) I did mention that jar files could be involved
B) Perhaps I'm not human, but I have successfully patched binary distribution images to fix bugs that annoyed me e.g. Copy-protected games to stop diskette wearing out, Ashton Tate/Borland DBase III & IV, 
C) I HAVE downloaded all the Ardiuno git repository; I though that that was obvious. If I haven't got ALL the source, I'm still prepared to do so. Not only can I run compilers, I write & modify both compilers and decompilers. 
D) As mentioned, I have and can run more capable terminal programs, BUT THEY STOP THE IDE FROM UPLOADING SKETCHES

Comment: The ide is crude and it only provides crude facilities. If you don't like it then write your own. You sound more than capable.